# Could not link assemblies. Reason: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.Forms solution, but after some cleaning & building, I'm unable to compile my Xamarin.iOS project anymore.
This project was recently migrated from PCL to a .NET Standard 1.6 project in VS2017 and compiled successfully in earlier builds. I was able to compile and run in iOS Simulator in Debug Mode, but after some cleaning and building (and adding and removing some NuGet packages) I can't run in this mode either.

```
Environment variables being passed to the tool:
2>  Xamarin.iOS 11.6.1 using framework: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.2.sdk
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(777,3): error : Could not link assemblies. Reason: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
2>  Tool /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch execution finished.
2>  MTouch: 2017-12-28T11:56:33.4882016-07:00 - Finalizado
2>Ejecución de la tarea "MTouch" terminada -- ERROR.
2>Compilación terminada del destino "_CompileToNative" en el proyecto "MyApp.iOS.csproj" -- ERROR.
2>
2>ERROR al compilar.
2>
2>"C:\_Sources\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.iOS\MyApp.iOS.csproj" (destino predeterminado) (1) ->
2>(_CoreCompileImageAssets destino) -> 
2>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(1198,3): warning : The app icon set "AppIcons" has an unassigned child.
2>
2>
2>"C:\_Sources\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.iOS\MyApp.iOS.csproj" (destino predeterminado) (1) ->
2>(_CompileToNative destino) -> 
2>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(777,3): error : Could not link assemblies. Reason: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Any ideas?
I'm using VS Community 2017, Version 15.5.2
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.5.2+27130.2010

Comment: Have you tried changing the build output verbosity? See if you get more details?

Comment: I actually changed to "Detailed" to display that. I just pick the most relevant part.

Comment: There are a lot of similar issues online, it seems to be the bug of xamairn. Can't you find any helpful workaround form them?

Comment: At the moment I just updated Xcode to 9.2 and set linker to "Don't link", It compiles but crashes at startup